# How to obtain a const qualified declval?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Base
{
    int f() const;
    double f();
};

struct Derived
: public Base
{
    template <typename T = decltype(std::declval<Derived>().f())> // Modify this
    T g() const;
};

int main()
{
    const Derived x;
    std::cout<<typeid(decltype(x.g())).name()<<std::endl; // Prints "d", not "i"
    return 0;
}
```

How to modify `decltype(std::declval<Derived>().f())` so that it will return `int` and not `double`?

I've tried `decltype(std::declval<const Derived>().f()` but it does not compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC 4.8.1 likes this:

```
template <typename T = decltype(std::declval<Base const>().f())>
```

You need to tell the compiler that the object through which you make the call is `const`.

You cannot specify `Derived` here in this `declval` because at the point of the call, `Derived` is an incomplete type.  In addition, you don't even need `Derived` as part of the `declval` since `f()` is a member of `Base`.

Comment: You changed `Derived` to `Base`. Why?

Comment: @0x499602D2:  Because at the point of the call, `Derived` is an incomplete type.  It is also not needed, since the call is actually on `Base`.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to use `Derived` in a context where it required to be complete, but it can't be complete yet as it is part of the method's return type which is required to complete the definition. This loop is impossible to solve for the compiler.

You need to use the base class with `std::declval<const Base>()` and your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Throw `declval` out the window; when your type expression is dependent on function parameters, class members, and/or `this` it is almost certainly easier and clearer to put it in a trailing return type where you can refer to them by name:

```
struct Derived
: public Base
{
    Derived() {}
    auto g() const -> decltype(f());
};
```

I added a user-provided default constructor to `Derived` so that `const Derived x;` is well-formed per §8.5/6.

Comment: In the context of this particular example, yes it works, but the question was more "general".

Comment: The question was "How do I obtain a declval which X" and your answer was "don't use declval."  It has been demonstrated that what OP was looking for can be accomplished.  I can't upvote this.

Comment: @DanielFrey C++11 8.5/6 "If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type
with a user-provided default constructor."

Comment: @JohnDibling The question is "How to modify decltype(std::declval<Derived>().f()) so that it will return int and not double?" and I modified it by eliminating "std::declval<Derived>()." and moving it from a template parameter to a trailing return type. It may not be the answer the OP was _expecting_, but it does show how to achieve the desired end with significantly less code.

Comment: @Casey:  I understand what you're trying to do, but I think the spirit of the question had using `declval` at it's core.  FWIW, I'm not going to d/v either.

Comment: @Casey You are right and Clang actually rejects the code. GCC OTOH accepted it. I checked for DRs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @DanielFrey [CWG issue 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) appertains. [GCC seems to have implemented the currently discussed resolution](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44499#c20) despite the issue still being open? Or perhaps it was re-opened in 2011. Correction: the issue is not "open", it is "drafting."